# Serving VueJS Builds via Express.js using history mode

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I want to serve vue js `dist/` via express js. I am using history router in vue js app.

The following are the api calls

1. api/
2. s-file/sending/:id
3. terms/get/:which

As i have figured out a solution in python [here](https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/ce735c07fd312e1605c79998fd3d8c30). I don't know how to do it in node js with `express`

The code i am using right now is

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (/api/.test(req.url))
        next();
    else {
        var file = "";
        if (req.url.endsWith(".js")) {
            file = path.resolve(path.join(distPath, req.url))
            res.header("Content-Type", "application/javascript; charset=utf-8");
            res.status(200);
            res.send(fs.readFileSync(file).toString());
        } else if (req.url.endsWith(".css")) {
            file = path.resolve(path.join(distPath, req.url))
            res.header("Content-Type", "text/css; charset=utf-8");
            res.status(200);
            res.send(fs.readFileSync(file).toString());

        } else {
            file = path.resolve(path.join(distPath, "index.html"))
            res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            res.status(200);
            res.send(fs.readFileSync(file).toString());
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: Im not clear about your requirement, is api/ is a rest api or is there any static file directories etc.. ?

Comment: all endpoints mentioned are REST Apis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very simpler one if anyone wants to use

Just add this below all the valid routes and above `app.listen`

```
app.all("*", (_req, res) => {
  try {
    res.sendFile('/absolute/path/to/index.html');
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

Make sure you have included

```
app.use(express.static('/path/to/dist/directory'));
```

Comment: Why is there an "async" when "await" is not being used in the function?

Comment: My man. You're the real mvp.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) that is referenced in the [vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).
This should solve your problems.

**Example using connect-history-api-fallback**

```
var express = require('express');
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var app = express();

// Middleware for serving '/dist' directory
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static('dist');

// 1st call for unredirected requests 
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

// Support history api
// this is the HTTP request path not the path on disk
app.use(history({
  index: '/index.html'
}));

// 2nd call for redirected requests
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: it will not work for vue routerlinks i.e fallbacks
and moreover i am getting `Cannot GET /`

Comment: My bad, have a look at the use of `connect-history-api-fallback` in my updated answer

Comment: **Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server**  after deploying to docker !! what does that mean ?

Comment: @LOG_TAG this error could have many causes either in your hosting configuration or in your server code. Consider opening a separate question where you give all the background information needed: (What are you trying to do? What is working? What isn’t? What have you tried so far)

Comment: @Benno sure thanks for responding, I'm dealing with same 'Serving VueJS Builds via Express.js" using google cloud run via gcloud! wondering it's going to be duplicate one :)

Comment: @LOG_TAG your question seems to be specific to setting up the docker hosting environment - that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Benno I tried both ways, but nothing working. do I need to change anything in vuejs build?

Comment: @Abhilash Please check the Vue docs here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html and make sure you did enable history mode in the router. If you don’t get it to work, please consider opening a new question and provide info on what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Can i serve more then one vuejs app using that middleware ? like serving the app and an admin page, each one of them as a separate vue app