# Vue.js dynamic router with node.js server - cannot serve the routes

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have the following routes inside of my vue app's files named routes.js:

```
[{
    path: '/',
    component: home
},
{
    path: '/about',
    component: about
},
{
    path: '/projects',
    component: projects
},
{
    path: '/contact',
    component: contact
},
{
    name: 'details',
    path: '/projects/:id',
    component: details
}
```

]

I also made my server.js:

```
    const express = require('express')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

//servs files from dist dir
app.use('/', serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))


const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(port)

console.log(`listening on ${port}`)
```

After I run `npm run build`, and `node server.js` in terminal - only page at '/' route is served correctly.
From other requests, I'm getting `Cannot GET/random-route-name`

All of routes are served locally on `npm run serve` without problems.

Is there any possibility for this to be solved, so that other routes can be displayed correctly on `node server` command ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check routes on your server and send appropriate page for each request. Better to use some middleware for that.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov is there any middleware to be recommended?

Comment: Write your own function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serving VueJS Builds via Express.js using history mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327143/serving-vuejs-builds-via-express-js-using-history-mode)

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, thanks bro! 
It helped me to find a solution. These are the lines I made by using this 'connenct-history-api-fallback' module: 

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static('dist');

app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

app.use(history());

//second call:
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

It solves everything in my case.